# Shuffling Rows and Columns

Tags: excel

I have to convert an Excel sheet of a wiring diagram into another format so that I can import it into another software program. I now have 4 columns that look like:

```
Connector:   Pin:  (to)  Connector:  Pin:
 Conn1        1           Conn2       3
 Conn2        4           Conn3       1
 Conn1        2           Conn2       2
 Conn1        2           Conn3       2
```

I need to list the connectors across the top and the corresponding pin-connections horizontally, so something like:

```
        Conn1 Conn2 Conn3
Pins:     1     3
                4     1
          2     2     2
```

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Write short program in c# to run through the excel sheet? Shouldn't be a problem I think. Btw what should be your ourput?